# Making Balls Bounce

Tags: javascript

//Initializing General Setup Variables

```
'''var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var h = canvas.height;
var w = canvas.width;
var sAngle = 0;
const PI = Math.PI;
var r = 10;
totalNum = 5;'''
```

//total num is the number of balls wanted

//Function to Create The Initial Positions of All The Balls

```
'''var initialPos = [];
function makePositions(){
for (var i = 1; i <= totalNum; i++) 
{initialPos.push([i*100*Math.random(),i*100*Math.random()])}
console.log(initialPos);
}
makePositions();'''
```

//Function to Draw Balls at initial positions in the array makePositions

```
function drawBalls (){
for (i = 0; i <= totalNum - 1; i++) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(initialPos[i][0], initialPos[i][1], r, sAngle, 2*PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
}
}
  drawBalls();
```

//Initializing Variables to Move Balls

```
var dt = 0.01;
var vx = 50;
var vy = 50;
```

//Creating New Positions With Velocities

```
function changePos (num){return num + vx*dt} //Chenges position based on velocity 
and time
function changePos2 (num){return num - vx*dt} //Chenges position based on velocity 
and time

var allPos = []; 
function move () {
allPos = [];
var newPos;
for (j = 0; j <= totalNum - 1; j++){
if (0 < initialPos[j][0]< 500 && 0 < initialPos[j][1]< 500)
{newPos = initialPos[j].map(changePos)}
if (initialPos[j][0] < 0 || initialPos[j][0] > w)
{var newPos = [changePos2(initialPos[j][0]),changePos(initialPos[j][1])]}
if (initialPos[j][1] < 0 || initialPos[j][1] > h) {var newPos = 
[changePos(initialPos[j][0]),changePos2(initialPos[j][1])]}
allPos.push(newPos); 
}
initialPos = allPos;
console.log(allPos)
}
```

/* new positions are pushed into the array allPos
map iterates through the array intiialPos and performs the changePos function on each element in the array */

//Clearing Canvas

```
function resetCanvas () {
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
}
```

//Drawing the Balls at their new positions

```
function drawBalls2 (){
for (var i = 0; i <= totalNum - 1; i++) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(allPos[i][0], allPos[i][1], r, sAngle, 2*PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
}
    }
```

//Drawing Balls -> Moving Balls -> Reset Canvas -> Draw

```
function ball (){
resetCanvas();
move();
drawBalls2();
}



setInterval(ball, 100 * dt);
```

I'm trying to make it so that in my move function when the balls hit the canvas borders, they bounce off in the opposite direction, however with my current parameters in my move function, it is not working. The balls are gathering in a corner and then freezing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are multiple flaws within your move function.

1) `0 < initialPos[j][0] < 500`
Checking for ranges inJavaScript dosn't work like this.
This will boil down to `(0 < initialPos[j][0]) < 500`. This gets evaluated to `0 or 1 < 500` which is true for all cases.

2) `initialPos[j].map(changePos)`
When I understood that correctly, `initialPos` is a two dimensional array,
containing an array with the positions for all balls.
But with the `map(changePos)` you're applying the X-vector to the X and Y coordinate of the ball.

3) You're not permanently changing the vector for the given ball (The cause for the ball being stuck)
Within your corner case blocks your applying the `changePos2` transformation correctly.
But since the new position will then be back into the bounds you're falling back to the normal `newPos = initialPos[j].map(changePos)` transition without changing the movement direction.

In order to solve that you'll need an array containing the vectors of each ball.
Then within the move loopapply this vector to the balls position. If the new position is out of the game, invert the vector component (x or y) and the ball will bounce off the wall again.